# How should I create index when there is OR between conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE type = 4 AND author_id IN (?, ?) AND post_id IN (?, ?)
```

As you know, `author_id IN (? , ?)` translates to `author_id = ? OR author_id = ?`. So should I create an index on `author_id` column?

In fact I'm trying to understand how MySQL treats with conditions when there is `OR` between them. I read this sentence somewhere:

> MySQL seems to ignore indices once it encounters an `OR`.

But I cannot understand the meaning of it. Can anybody? Overall what indexes do I need for query above?

Comment: Replace `DELETE` with `SELECT type, author_id, post_id` then prepend `EXPLAIN` and run the query using a MySQL client. Create any indexes you want and the `EXPLAIN` query will tell you what indexes are used. Read more about the meaning of the [`EXPLAIN` output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html).

Comment: basic rule of thumb: add an index to any field used in a `decision` context, which is `where`, `join`, `order by, `etc...

Comment: @MarcB Well sometimes we need to add a multiple column index. Ex: `(type, author_id, post_id)` .. But that's true when there is `AND` between those condition. I want to know how should I do when there is  `OR` between them ...

Comment: then it won't really work. indexes are examined left->right in field ordering. `A or B` would require the `B` field to have an index where it's left-most in the index definition, because doing the `B` portion of the `or` is essentially independent of the `A` portion. any records matched by A are irrelevant for the B match, because it's an `or`.

Comment: @MarcB I see. Just may you please tell me should I add index for which columns of query above exactly?

Comment: revamp the indexes so the fields you're `or`ing appear first in the index. e.g. `A or B` should have indexes `(B,C,D)` instead of `(C,B,D)` or whatever. And if those fields are used in multiple indexes. consider making them indexed completely separately, `(B)` and `(C,D)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that `OR` usually prevents effective use of indexes. A query can generally only use one index per table when process the `WHERE` clause. So if you have a condition like

```
WHERE col1 = 1 OR col2 = 2
```

it can't use any single index to find all the matching rows. You're generally best off splitting the query into two and using `UNION`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE
WHERE col1 = 1
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE
WHERE col2 = 2
```

However, I think I read somewhere that in simple cases MySQL is able to perform this transformation automatically. Check the `EXPLAIN` output for your query.

But when the `OR` condition involves the same column, it can still use the index, e.g. if you have

```
WHERE col1 = 1 OR col1 = 2
```

it just has to look up these two index entries in the index for `col1`. And this is what it does when you write:

```
WHERE col1 IN (1, 2)
```

However, your query is more complex than this, because it's also combining multiple conditions with `AND`. If you were just using `=` comparisons, it could optimize this with a multi-column index, e.g.

```
INDEX (type, author_id, post_id)
```

But when you have multiple `IN` conditions, this can't be done, because it would need to enumerate all the combinations.

```
type = 4 AND author_id IN (1, 2) AND post_id IN (10, 20)
```

would require looking up all these indexes:

```
4, 1, 10
4, 1, 20
4, 2, 10
4, 2, 20
```

I don't think MySQL will generate all the combination like this (but I could be wrong -- check the `EXPLAIN` output to see if it can).

Instead, it will select whichever index it thinks will be most effective, use that to find a the rows that match that part of the condition, and scan those rows to evaluate the remaining conditions.

Comment: Great explanations, upvote ..! Just finally any index won't be useful for my query?

Comment: I guess my explanation wasn't so great if you need to ask that. It will pick one of the indexes and use that, and scan the rows for the other conditions.

Comment: Ah .. Do you mean just one index will be useful? So should I add an separated index on `type`, `author_id`, `post_id` and let MySQL decides to uses which index?

Comment: Did you try the `EXPLAIN` I suggested, to see if it can use the composite index?

Comment: Yeah I used `EXPLAIN` for my query, but result is kinda vague .. I cannot understand anything of the `EXPLAIN`'s result.

Comment: Seems pretty clear: key = NULL means it's not using any indexes.

Comment: I've added an index on `type` column and here is the result http://i.stack.imgur.com/m6dYp.png

Comment: It's very strange that it didn't use the `(type, other_id, author_id)` index, since a multi-column index is an index on the prefix columns.

Comment: Ok, just tell me which one is better? [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5oJw4.png) or [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m6dYp.png)

Comment: Look at the `rows` column. Scanning 2 rows is better than scanning 7 rows.

Comment: This is turning into a tutoring session on how to read `EXPLAIN`, I'm not interested in continuing it.

Comment: Alright .. At least I've learned three things tonight .. 1. A query only use one index per table 2. the meaning of *key* in the result of EXPLAIN 3. the meaning of *rows* in the result of EXPLAIN ..! thank you for them :-)

Comment: You know, that's wrong which *a query only uses one index per table*. MySQL is executing an *index_merge* for this query `. . . WHERE id = ? OR col1 = ?` on the `col1` and the `primary` key . So sometimes `WHERE col1 OR col2` is much faster than using `UNION` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727628/using-or-operator-vs-union-operator